# How to showcase stats of live crowdfun in a website?

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, contract-invocation, erc-20, ethereumjs

I am not completely sure where to find the answer to this. I went over the etherscan.io documentation and I was still confused. I am not sure if I simply create an API related to my account and then copy the address of the contract that I wish to show stats for and insert it into the https code.

The part that says "apikey=YourApiKeyToken" in the documentation confuses me as I don't know if thats the API from an specific contract or simply the API I created?

Any information is greatly appreciated!

Comment: they are saying this: "To use the API service please create a FREE Api-Key Token from within the ClientPortal->MyApiKey area which you can then use with all your api requests" on their website, so I suppose you must create an account in their system and they will give you this `apikey`

Answer (score 0):

Etherscan is a service that monitors the Ethereum blockchain for you. The Ethereum blockchain is totally separate - there is no "API key" for either the blockchain or for an individual contract.

With an etherscan API key, you can make API requests for any contract or address on the blockchain, since all that information is public anyway. The only purpose of the key is to protect etherscan from abuse - so that if you put too much load on their service, they can block your key.